# Find the first paragraph of a each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append the first paragraph in every `.post` within `.index`

http://jsfiddle.net/syehC/

```
<div class="index">

        <div class="post">
            <p>append me!</p>
            <p>paragraph</p>
            <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
        <div class="post">
            <p>append me!</p>
            <p>paragraph</p>
            <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
        <div class="post">
            <p>append me!</p>
            <p>paragraph</p>
            <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single">
            <p>paragraph</p>
            <p>paragraph</p>
            <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
```

And I have tried both of the following:

```
$('.index .post p:first').append('...');

$('.index .post p:first').each(function () {
    $(this).append('...');
});
```

But they only seem to get the first paragraph in the document, not the first **of each** `post`.

Would anyone know a solution, and explain why this isn't working?

Comment: :first only gets the first. you want the first ***child*** of each.

Comment: `$('.index .post p:first-child')`

Comment: Like @KevinB said, use [first-child](http://jsfiddle.net/syehC/3/).

Comment: `$('.index .post p:first-of-type')` is best. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5ayH7/1/)

Find all the elements which match `.index .post` and for each element find the first paragraph and append to it:

```
$('.index .post').each( function(){
    $( 'p:first', this ).append( '...' );
} );
```

A version with a single selector is:

```
$('.index .post p:first-child').append('...');
```

- The [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) pseudo-class only matches a single element (the first in the DOM hierarchy).
- The [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) finds the first match for each of its parents.

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between `$( 'p:first', this )` and `$( '.index .post p:first') ?

Comment: The [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) pseudo-class will only match a single element (the first to be matched). So `'.index .post p:first'` will look for the first element which matches the selector `'.index .post p'` regardless of how many matches there are. `.index .post` can match multiple elements and then you can look for the `:first` paragraph element in each of those matches.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `:first-child` instead of `:first`

```
$('.index .post p:first-child').each(function () {
    $(this).append('...');
});
```

[:first](http://api.jquery.com/first/) matches only a single element, the [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector can match more than one: one for each parent.

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/syehC/4/)

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between them?

Comment: @tmyie First will select the first element in the collection. first-child will make a collection by selecting the first child.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like:

```
$('.index .post').each(function(){
    $(this).find('p:first').append('my text to append');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a variant of the answer @Sachin provided.

You should use the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class. This way, even if the first child of `.post` is a `<div>`, it will still select the first `<p>` element.

```
$('.index .post p:first-of-type').each(function () {
    $(this).append('...');
});
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KTj42/1/

Read more about [`:first-of-type`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/) at CSS Tricks.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to select by jquery in console you'll see that you only have the first paragraph on the returned array, because you're are filtering it. 
You can do it this way, i think it is more readable. You do an each over all .post and for each one you will find the first paragraph on it and append '...'

```
$('.index .post').each(function(){
   $(this).find('p:first').append('...');
})
```